# Problemas al visualizar mi reporte.jasper en un Jpanel

Tags: ireport

Tengo un problema al visualizar uno de mis reportes en un **Jpanel** de mi interfaz gráfica.

Cabe mencionar que el reporte que me dá problemas, lo puedo visualizar en mi máquina aun después de abrirlo en la interfaz de mi aplicación que ya esta generada, es decir, abro mi `app.jar`, doy click en un `jButton` para generar el reporte, llamado "Caratula" y me lo muestra, pero al ejecutar mi aplicación en otra máquina y dar clic sobre el `jButton`, no se muestra dicho reporte en el `Jpanel` y tampoco me marca error, solo se queda en blanco mi `Jpanel` y ni siquiera muestra los menús de arriba donde se puede hacer zoom etc.

Este es el reporte generado:

[image: Reporte Generado]

El código que uso en el ActionPerformed del JButton, es el siguiente:

```
try {
    //Aquí obtengo la fecha que uso en uno de los parametros...                 
    Calendar cal = dateChooserComboFechaCaratula.getSelectedDate();
    Date date = cal.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat formatFechaSQL = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String fechaFin = formatFechaSQL.format(date);
    String dir_current = System.getProperty("user.dir") ;
    String file_report = dir_current+"/Reportes/Caratula/Cartula_general.jasper";
    String dir_mañana = dir_current+"/Reportes/Caratula/caratula_mañana/";
    String dir_tarde = dir_current+"/Reportes/Caratula/caratula_tarde/";
    String noche_1 = dir_current+"/Reportes/Caratula/Caratula_noche_1/";
    String dir = dir_current+"/Reportes/Caratula/";
    String noche_2 = dir_current+"/Reportes/Caratula/Caratula_noche_2/";
    String gasolin = dir_current+"/Reportes/Caratula/gasolinera/";

    File fichero = new File(file_report);
    JasperReport jr;
    jr = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(fichero);
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR_MAÑANA",dir_mañana);
    parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR_TARDE",dir_tarde);
    parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR_NOCHE_1",noche_1);
    parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR",dir);
    parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR_NOCHE_2",noche_2);
    parameters.put("SUBREPORT_DIR_GASOLINERA",gasolin);
    parameters.put("fecha", fechaFin);

    JasperPrint jasperprint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr,parameters, DbConexion.getConnection());//new JREmptyDataSource()
    JasperViewer jviewer = new JasperViewer(jasperprint);
    refrescar_Ventana();
    jPanel2.removeAll();
    jPanel2.add(jviewer.getContentPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
} catch (JRException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JIFCaratula.this,ex, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(JIFCaratula.this, "No fue posible generar el reporte, revise que las rutas sean las adecuadas", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

intenta con esto en tu objeto jPanel2, y que veo que no le estas agregando un JScrollPanel a tu jpanel :

```
  jPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  jPanel2.repaint();
  jPanel2.add(jviewer);
  jPanel2.revalidate();
```

espero te funcione.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo y respuesta, lo probare y te digo que tal anda!

Comment: Probé con el código recomendado, solo omití está linea de código: <code> jPanel2.add(jviewer); </code> y deje la que tengo: <code> jPanel2.add(jviewer.getContentPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);</code> me muestra el reporte, solo que no entiendo por que lo muestra hasta que maximizo el JFrame!

Comment: y el resultado fue ? si omitiste esa, como estas agregando el reporte al panel ?

Comment: Ignoro si me sea de utilidad la linea de código que yo tengo!  <code> jPanel2.add(jviewer.getContentPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);</code>

Comment: si osea lo agregas como te puse de ejemplo o como lo estas haciendo actualmente , pero debes agregar el jviewer al jpanel de una u otra manera. pero prueba como te lo pase a ver cual es el resultado

Comment: Entiendo, muchas gracias. se queda en blanco el JPanel, pero al maximizar el JFrame, ya se muestra el reporte, no comprendo por que hasta que maximizo se muestra.

Comment: Probé con la opción que me diste, solo le agregue el getContentPane() y ya me lo muestra bien, hasta con el jScrollPanel, muchas gracias y agradezco tu tiempo!

Comment: Vale , para eso estamos :), no se te olvide marcar la respuesta como correcta si te sirve para que otros puedan utilizar los mismo y asi evitamos preguntas y respuestas duplicadas